# How to get to "extended" prototype properties or function in JavaScript? Common practice in jQuery pliugins

Tags: javascript, oop, object, jquery-plugins, properties

I'm beginner with OOP in JavaScript. I've tried few things but its obvious that i don't understand code.
Here's my problem:
I have a plugin for showing calendar - glDataPicker. It is initialised on input tag like this:

`$('#my_input_id').glDatePicker();//parameters may be passed`

1. So i am assuming that after deploying script to my site `glDatePicker.min.js` inputs in DOM got new method glDatePicker? Am i right here?

Then it has `hide` and `show` methods defined:

```
// Public methods
    glDatePicker.prototype =
    {
        show: function() {
            // Hide others and show this calendar
            $.each($('.gldp-el').not(this.el), function(i, o) {
                if(o.length) { o.options.onHide(o.calendar) ; }
            });

            // Show this calendar
            this.options.onShow(this.calendar);
        },

        hide: function() {
            if(this.options && !this.options.showAlways) {
                this.options.onHide(this.calendar);
            }
        },
```

So my question is how can I call method `hide' from outside the plugin code?
I've tried:

`$('#my_input_id').glDatePicker().calendar.hide()`
-> Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined(…)

and so on but i can't hide the calendar. How can i get to this method from global context?

Comment: there is an option called 'showAlways', set it to false

Comment: it's set to false already, I need call `hide` from main script on some events, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('[gldp-el='+ $('#my_input_id').attr('gldp-id') +']').hide()

$('[gldp-el='+ $('#my_input_id').attr('gldp-id') +']').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have found, what I need:

```
// Doing it in a single pass
var myDatePicker = $('#example1').glDatePicker(
{
   showAlways: true,
   selectableDOW: [0, 2, 3]
}).glDatePicker(true);

// Or you can do it with multiple calls
$('example1').glDatePicker(
{
    showAlways: true,
    selectableDOW: [0, 2, 3]
});

var myDatePicker = $('example1').glDatePicker(true);
```

now I can:

```
myDatePicker.hide();
```

so that menas that first `glDatePicker` doesn't reutrn object.